# Fundamental group of filled in rectangle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider the following topological space $Y$, which is a filled-in rectangle where the opposite sides are identified with each other. I am curious as to how to compute $\pi_1(Y)$. I am looking for an approach that doesn't use cell complexes but ultimately uses Van Kampen. To this end, we want to somehow decompose $Y$ into two open, path connected sets with path connected intersection. Intuitively, it seems to me that we want such a decomposition to correspond to the interior and boundary of the rectangle. The only idea that I have is to consider the map $p$ that goes along the boundary once clockwise, so that, when applying Van Kampen, we ultimately mod out by the cyclic  group generated by $[p]$ of order $4$.

Overall, I only have a vague idea. I would really appreciate seeing how one could compute this rigorously.

[image]

Comment: The space you describe is called a torus.

Comment: Take a peek at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLcr-DWVEto , perhaps the clearest way *to see* (as opposed to claculate) how the two basic paths *around the torus* (one "embracing" the hole, the other one around it) commute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is in the right direction.

If you decompose the torus into the interior region, say $U$, and the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the boundary, say $V$, then the interior region $U$ is clearly contractible (and hence $\pi_1(U)=\{1\}$), and the boundary region $V$ is a space that looks like a figure-8 space. (Indeed, the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the boundary deformation retracts to the boundary, and the boundary is exactly the figure-8 space.) The fundamental group of a figure-8 space is a free group with 2 generators, say, $\alpha, \beta$, so $\pi_1(V)=\langle\alpha, \beta\rangle$. The intersection $U\cap V$ looks topologically like a (thickened) circle. Its fundamental group is just an infinite cyclic group generated by a loop going around near the boundary of the rectangle, which is $\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-1}$ in $\pi_1(V)$.

Thus, by the van Kampen's theorem, the fundamental group of the torus is $\pi_1(U)*\pi_1(V)/\pi_1(U\cap V) = \langle\alpha, \beta\rangle/\langle \alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-1}\rangle  = \langle \alpha, \beta \vert \alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-1}\rangle\simeq \mathbb{Z}^2$

FYI: In fact, in general the fundamental group of a surface obtained by identifying pairs of edges of a polygon can be obtained in this way: generators are the edges, and the relation is exactly the one corresponding to the loop along the boundary.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately my issue is that I can't see how to use Van Kampen at the end. It may be a simple application, but I don't see how exactly it's used here.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 I just expanded the original answer a little bit.